# Lost my phone, can't login Apple ID

Tags: apple-id

My phone number is changed, so now I can't log in to my Apple ID as it sends the two-factor authentication code to the previous phone number. Also, I'm not logged in to any other Apple product.

I requested the "forgot password" change, and after a few weeks, I received an SMS to the new phone number, that now I can start the change process. But the recovery still asks for the previous phone number.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest following Apple's guide on recovering an Apple-ID:

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204921

In particular you want to visit this web site to start the process:

https://iforgot.apple.com/

If these are the steps you've already taken, and you still cannot gain access even after waiting the given period of time - I would call Apple Support to ask if they can recover your account for you based on some other means of authentication.